# No Items in RecyclerView after adding item in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a name in sqlite and as soon as data is inserted in sqlite, i am updating the recyclerview. Following is my code

```
public class DbContract {
    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_OK=0;
    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_FAILED=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactdb";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="contactinfo";
    public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String SYNC_STATUS="syncstatus";
}

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME+" (id integer primary key autoincrement, "+DbContract.NAME+" text,"+
            DbContract.SYNC_STATUS+" integer);";
    public static final String DROP_TABLE="drop table if exists "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DbContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void saveToLocalDatabase(String name,int syncstatus,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContract.NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS,syncstatus);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor readFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String[] projection={DbContract.NAME,DbContract.SYNC_STATUS};
      //  Log.i("frff", "readFromLocalDatabase: "+projection.toString());
        return (sqLiteDatabase.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null));
    }

    public void updateLocalDatabase(String name, int syncstatus,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS,syncstatus);
        String selection = DbContract.NAME+" LIKE ? ";
        String[] selection_args={name};
        sqLiteDatabase.update(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selection_args);
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;
    private ArrayList<Contact> arrayList;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                saveToLocalStorage(name);
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void submitName(View view) {

    }

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    private void readFromLocalStorage() {
        arrayList.clear();
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.NAME));
            int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS));
            arrayList.add(new Contact(name, sync_status));

        }
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private void saveToLocalStorage(String name) {
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (checkNetworkConnection()) {

        } else {
            dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(name, DbContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED, sqLiteDatabase);
        }
        readFromLocalStorage();
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Whenever an item is added through `edittext` and button is cliked,  no item can be seen in my `recyclerview` . I am not getting any error in my logcat and neither does the app crashes. Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `RE-LAUNCH` app then ??

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: show your java class.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya you mean Pojo class?

Comment: public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private int sync_status;

    public Contact(String name, int sync_status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sync_status = sync_status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSync_status() {
        return sync_status;
    }

    public void setSync_status(int sync_status) {
        this.sync_status = sync_status;
    }
}

Comment: no. main activity..add this question section.

Comment: Please check the question , I have added MainActivity

Comment: Try to log arrayList after while loop inside readFromLocalStorage() and check if values are present in database or not.

Comment: @R.R.M i was missing a bracket in creating table statement. But still it does ot solves my problem. I added a log statement but doesn't prints to the logcat

Comment: @R.R.M it is not going the while loop

Comment: It means your database is empty.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
    public class DbContract {
    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_OK=0;
    public static final int SYNC_STATUS_FAILED=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactdb";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="contactinfo";
    public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String SYNC_STATUS="syncstatus";
    }

    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME+" id integer primary key autoincrement, "+DbContract.NAME+" text,"+
            DbContract.SYNC_STATUS+" integer);";
    public static final String DROP_TABLE="drop table if exists "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DbContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void saveToLocalDatabase(String name,int syncstatus,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContract.NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS,syncstatus);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor readFromLocalDatabase(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String[] projection={DbContract.NAME,DbContract.SYNC_STATUS};
      //  Log.i("frff", "readFromLocalDatabase: "+projection.toString());
        return (sqLiteDatabase.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null));
    }

    public void updateLocalDatabase(String name, int syncstatus,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS,syncstatus);
        String selection = DbContract.NAME+" LIKE ? ";
        String[] selection_args={name};
        sqLiteDatabase.update(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selection_args);
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;
    private ArrayList<Contact> arrayList;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                saveToLocalStorage(name);
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void submitName(View view) {

    }

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    private void readFromLocalStorage() {
        arrayList.clear();
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.NAME));
            int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.SYNC_STATUS));
            arrayList.add(new Contact(name, sync_status));

        }
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private void saveToLocalStorage(String name) {
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (checkNetworkConnection()) {

        } else {
            dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(name, DbContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED, sqLiteDatabase);
        }
        dbHelper.close();
        readFromLocalStorage();

    }
}
```

Comment: what changes you made?

Comment: See saveToLocalStorage(). I have putted dbHelper.close(); first.

Comment: Is log of values of projection printing?

Answer (score 0):

why are you checking internet connection would you check that? 
i think i notice that in your code compiler check connection and compile if condition and not make any entry to database please check that once.

Comment: i need to sync my sqlite with my sql later thats why i am checking for internet

Comment: so do one thing put this code
 dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(name, DbContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED, sqLiteDatabase);
       into savetolocaldatabase, and try again

Comment: I need to check for internet. It is not going in else clause. I have put my emulator in airplane mode